# How to convert string to datetime object then create If statement when time is on the hour

Tags: python

I'm reading (actually scraping) an RSS feed of NOAA buoy data. One of the data is the date and time the data was collected at the buoy. So the string I am extrapolating is in this format: January 10, 2023 9:48 am

But if the time is on the hour, say 'January 10, 2023 10:00 am', the feed produces an extra variable that throws my output off.

Thus, my code would check to see if the feed is on the hour and change the variables, like so:

```
air_temp = rows[7]
water_temp = rows[8]

if [time minutes = '00']:
   air_temp = rows[7]
   water_temp = rows[8]
```

I'm assuming I would need to change the time string to datetime in order to write the If statement? (Otherwise, I'm happy with the string format as is for my output.)

Answer (score 1):

to check if the time is on the hour, you could do this to convert it to a datetime, then check if the minutes are zero:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
date = 'January 10, 2023 10:00 am'
datetime = dt.strptime(s, '%B %d, %Y %H:%M %p')
minute = datetime.minute

if minute == 0:
    do whatever
```

you could also do this which requires less thinking about the date format :)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime` for the same and convert your input time format to python's datetime data type.

```
import datetime

input_str = 'January 10, 2023 9:48 am'
input_time_format = '%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p'

datetime_str = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_str, input_time_format)
print(datetime_str.minute)
if datetime_str.minute == 0:
    pass
```

You can check more details about input format here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: if you have got your solution then feel free to mark as accepted answer.